# How to use base_template variable in Django login.html

Tags: django, django-templates, django-login

I have a very simple Django 3.1 project that uses the basic login-authentication found in the Mozilla tutorial (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication).

It works great, but **I'd like to change the extends base_generic line to a variable.**

**For example, logged_out.html, currently looks like this:**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <p>Logged out!</p>
  <a href="{% url 'login'%}">Click here to login again.</a>
{% endblock %}
```

**I'd like it to look like this:**

```
{% extends base_template %}  <-- Here's the change I'd like to make

{% block content %}
  <p>Logged out!</p>
  <a href="{% url 'login'%}">Click here to login again.</a>
{% endblock %}
```

I've been able to do this successfully for all the templates that I create, but I can't figure out how to do this for the "built-in" login-authentication pages, such as login.html, logged_out.html, password_reset_form.html, etc

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define your own template and change urls.py. Example changing a template for auth_views.LogoutView:

```
urlpatterns = [

path('logout/',
   auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='customers/logout.html'), 
   name='logout'),
]
```

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know that, but I"m OK with the template, I just want to pass a base_template variable to logged_out.html or login.html that I control somewhere else, preferably in views.py.

Comment: @SqueezeOJ: try to use view context. Not sure if it works though...

Comment: I'm still a Django Newb, so I'm not exactly sure how I'd do that.